# Android-show keyboard above popupmenu

Tags: java, android, popupmenu

I have a edit text where we type a restaurant name and while typing I want to show a popupmenu with restaurant list based on text typed. But keyboard is showing back of popup menu as:
[Click here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnUGU.png) 
I want my popup menu to fit above keyboard.
Here is my code to show popup menu:

```
final EditText restaurant = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.reservation_edit_text_restaurant);
restaurant.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(getContext(),restaurant);
        //get all the kitchen name from database
        List<String> kitchenNameList = getKitchenName();
        for (int j = 0; j < kitchenNameList.size(); ++j){
            popupMenu.getMenu().add(kitchenNameList.get(j));
        }

        popupMenu.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

    }
});
```

Comment: "But keyboard is showing below popup menu. I want my popup menu to fit above keyboard"  That sounds like you're saying its doing what you want.  You need to describe what you want much better-  possibly with pictures of what you have and what you want.

Comment: Sorry for my grammar mistake....Please see the edited post @GabeSechan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of EditText use AutoCompleteTextView:

```
 <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/Months"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:width="250dip" /> 

 import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;

public class AutoCompleteString extends Activity implements  OnItemClickListener, OnItemSelectedListener  {


    // Initialize variables

    AutoCompleteTextView textView=null;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    //These values show in autocomplete
    String item[]={
              "January", "February", "March", "April",
              "May", "June", "July", "August",
              "September", "October", "November", "December"
            };

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);

        setContentView(R.layout.auto_complete_string);


        // Initialize AutoCompleteTextView values

            // Get AutoCompleteTextView reference from xml
            textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.Months);

            //Create adapter    
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, item);

            textView.setThreshold(1);

           //Set adapter to AutoCompleteTextView
            textView.setAdapter(adapter);
            textView.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
            textView.setOnItemClickListener(this);


    }


    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Log.d("AutocompleteContacts", "onItemSelected() position " + position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(
                INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // Show Alert       
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Position:"+arg2+" Month:"+arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Log.d("AutocompleteContacts", "Position:"+arg2+" Month:"+arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2));

    }

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

Hope so,it will help you.[Source code and output is here](http://androidexample.com/Show_AutoComplete_Suggestions_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=105)

Comment: Thank you @lisha I wanted same as you suggested

Comment: That doesn't answer the question at all.